# Set screenshot path from default project location to different folder location

Tags: python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I have a suite which has 50 test cases. When I execute my suite, I get all the failed screenshots listed in the project's folder. I want to point and store those screenshots to a different directory with the name of the test case. I wanted it to be a one time setup than doing it explicitly for every test cases.

Comment: Have you noticed `Set Screenshot Directory` keyword? http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Set%20Screenshot%20Directory

Answer (score 1):

There's quite a few ways to change the screenshots default directory.

One way is to set the `screenshot_root_directory` argument when importing Selenium2Library. See the [importing section](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Importing) of Selenium2Library's documentation, and [importing libraries](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#importing-libraries) in the user guide.

Another way is to use the [Set Screenshot Directory](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Set%20Screenshot%20Directory) keyword, which will do pretty much the same thing as specifying a path when importing the library. Though, using this keyword you can set the path to a new one whenever you like. For example, you could make it so that each test case could have it's own screenshot directory using this keyword. According to your question, this may be the best solution.

And finally, you may also post-process screenshots using an external tool, or even a listener, that would move all screenshots to another directory. Previously mentioned solutions are in most cases much better, but you still may want to do this in some cases, where say, the directory where you want screenshots to be saved would be created only after the tests have finished executing.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to do the follow:

1. For new directory, you should put the following immediately after where you open a browser such:

`Open Browser    ${URL}    chrome
 Set screenshot directory    ${OUTPUT FILE}${/}..${/}${TEST_NAME}${/}`

2. For replace the screenshot name from the default to your own name, create the following keyword:

`sc
    Capture page screenshot    filename=${SUITE_NAME}-{index}.png`

Then, create another keyword and run it on Setup's test case:

```
    Register Keyword To Run On Failure    sc
```

In the above example, I created a new folder with the test case name, which create a screenshot (in case of failure) with the name of suite project name (instead of 'selenium-screenshot-1.png').

Comment: I tried as you have mentioned and it saves the screenshot in a different location with the expected screenshot name. But , when I open the log that is stored in the default location , I am not able to view the screenshot in that log.html

Comment: Ofer ,can you give more input on the above

Comment: How the screenshot path and name represented in the XML? Is it as it should be or wrong?